# jQuery...populating multiple dropdowns

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have an ajax call like so and for each result, I am displaying a dropdown menu like so:

```
$.each(results, function (key, value) {
     html += "<select id='vendorDropdown'><option value='0'>-- Select Vendor --</option></select>"
}
```

and I am populating the dropdown with another ajax call:

```
$.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
                    url: "/vendorProject/api/connection/getVendors",
                    dataType: 'json',
                    cache: false,
                    success: function (results) {
                        var vendorDropdown = $("#vendorDropdown");
                        $.each(results, function (row, value) {
                            vendorDropdown.append($("<option />").val(value.Vendor_ID).text(value.Vendor_Name));
                        });
                    }
                });
```

my problem is that this only populates the first dropdown and not any others, this is due because they all have the same id...what I am trying to do now is make the id unique with the value:

```
$.each(results, function (key, value) {
         html += "<select id='vendorDropdown-" + value +"'><option value='0'>-- Select Vendor --</option></select>"
    }
```

my question is, how would I target these dropdowns with the unique id in the other ajax call ?

Comment: Why don't use `class` instead of `id`? Like <select id='vendorDropdown" class="vendorDropdown"> and select via class `$('.vendorDropdown')`

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
var cnt = 0;
$.each(results, function (key, value) {
  html += "<select id='vendorDropdown-" + value + i +"'><option value='0'>-- Select Vendor --</option></select>"
  i++;
}
```